# Sometimes having Excel export problems

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a problem, I'm importing cycling a Table to *Excel.*

My code is look like this :

```
#WINAPI
#Excel
SysExcelApplication     excel;
SysExcelWorkbooks       books;
SysExcelWorkbook        book;
SysExcelWorksheets      sheets;
SysExcelWorksheet       sheet;
SysExcelCells           cells;
SysExcelCell            cell;
SysExcelRange           columns;

while select myTable
{
    cell = sheet.cells().item(row, col);
    cell.value(myTable.FieldI);
    sheet.columns().autoFit();
    col++;

    cell = sheet.cells().item(row, col);
    cell.value(myTable.FieldII);
    sheet.columns().autoFit();
    col++;

    row++;
    col=1;
}
// when the cycle end save my file
```

But sometimes I give an error look like message debug

"*Wrong argument types in variable assignment*"  [image: ErrorMessege]

or

"*The number of arguments provided is different from the number of arguments accepted by the method*"

But the weird thing is if i try againg to re-launch the export I will not get the errors.
I have  this problem

I have same code and same data.
When I generate the file the excle rows are perfect.
I have this problem in 50% of these cases.

The rows created are 1700 more less.
What does it depend on? I have  a lot rows? Or other?

I share the same question found on web [Some question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/202857/526010#526010) ,I tried to use, but did't solved my problem:
I add more information not slved my problem [change settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadaxsupport/2009/06/18/error-executing-code-the-method-has-been-called-with-an-invalid-number-of-parameters/)

Thanks in advice,

enjoy

Comment: Please verify any of your values have comma separator for numeric and date values.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep Muttikulangara Vasu, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have right separator.Sometimes I can create the File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when develop any export Excel had this problem, when many rows. If there are few rows it works perfect.

For this cases always change the excel export for CSV export. The code to export csv file never fail and work perfect!

Here I leave an example to export csv file with 5 rows.

***Code:***

```
static void ExportCSV(Args _args)
{
    Commaio     file;
    container   lineCSV;
    #File
    str         DatosLinea[500];
    int         _i;
    str         filename;
    Dialog      dialog;
    DialogField dialogFileName;

    ;

    dialog         = new Dialog("Path CSV");
    dialogFileName = dialog.addField(ExtendedTypeStr("FilenameSave"),"Path File:");

    if (dialog.run())
    {
        filename = dialogFileName.value();
    }

    if (!filename)
    {
        return;
    }

    file = new Commaio((filename), 'W'); //Path + file name.csv
    file.outFieldDelimiter(';');
    if( !file || file.status() != IO_Status::Ok)
    {
        throw error("File Cannot be opened");
    }

    DatosLinea[1] = "Col 1";
    DatosLinea[2] = "Col 2";
    DatosLinea[3] = "Col 3";
    DatosLinea[4] = "Col 4";
    DatosLinea[5] = "Col 5";

    _i = 1;
    lineCSV = conNull();
    while(_i <= 5){
        lineCSV += DatosLinea[_i];
        _i += 1;
    }

    file.write(lineCSV);

    info("Export end");
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks @Jonathan Bravetti for  your reply, but there is any way to export to xls without problem?

Comment: Or do you know some Fix ?

Comment: I really do not know. The only solution I found (and I do not like) close and save excel file every 200 lines.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Jonathan Bravetti. Work well.